# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server - ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am using ASP.Net MVC 3 (Entity Framework) with Sql server 2008. Connection string is fine in web.config. But sometimes i get the following exception from my application:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Generated: Wed, 02 May 2012 05:05:21 GMT

System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginWithFailover(Boolean useFailoverHost, ServerInfo primaryServerInfo, String failoverHost, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at MyApp.Data.UserRepository.GetUserDetails(String username)
   at MyApp.Core.Services.SiteService.GetUserDetails(String username, Int64 userId)
   at MyApp.PublicSite.Web.Controllers.BaseController.Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at MyApp.PublicSite.Web.Controllers.BaseController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The Connection string is:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyAppDBContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyAppDB.csdl|res://*/MyAppDB.ssdl|res://*/MyAppDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=MyAppDB;persist security info=True;user id=USERID;Password=PASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This exception occurs randomly and not able to get/reproduce it everytime. Any possible settings i may be missing here? Please suggest.

Comment: When this error occurs,Is your PC in network or not? I think you should check your LAN or Internet connection first.

Comment: In Local its not happening, i get this exception only from the deployed server.

Comment: @Prasad check the connection string I have provided....

Comment: Hi. Were you able to find a solution to this? We are having the same problem and we couldn't figure out why. I would be really glad if you could help. We also get this error occasionally, not always.

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that it sometimes/mostly work (as you say):

- The connection string is OK
- SQL is configured right (i.e. allowing remote connections etc.)

The only reason this could be is network drops between your server (your code) and SQL Server, or that SQL Server is shut down from some reason.

Comment: When i access the same page from where i got this exception, it works, so the Server shutdown may not be reason. And also the website and sql server are in the same server, so I am not sure whether the network drops may be a reason.

Comment: [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=A+network-related+or+instance-specific+error+occurred+while+establishing+a+connection+to+SQL+Server) this error gives a lot of possible solutions. Did you get over them? Also, specifically, please run `ping -t localhost` (or your SQL machine name), leave it running for a while and see if you lose packets from time to time.

Comment: i have tried those option from Google, all the options given there are configured properly, but still getting this exception :(. Also i have checked the ping and i there is reply without any failure.

Comment: Googling brought me to this page!!

Answer (score 0):

to allow the remote connections we need set the property to [true for tcp/IP in sql server configuration manager](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/ea9f0e79-ef69-4d47-9862-d53a1e460003/)

Answer (score 0):

We have to check following thing for this

1.Check Tcp/IP settings in sqlserver configuration manager settings.If it is disable ,[make sure we have to enable the status for TCP/IP](http://forums.asp.net/t/1827197.aspx/1?a%20network%20related%20or%20instance%20specific%20error%20occurred%20while%20establishing%20a%20connection%20to%20sql%20server)

2.Add port to fire wall exception at fire settings.
Details for sql port:

Name : SQL

Port Number: 1433

Protocol: Select TCP

Answer (score -1):

Try this one....

```
<add name="MyAppDBContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=MyAppDB;persist security info=True;user id=USERID;Password=PASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have edited my answer.....

Comment: It gives the error: System.ArgumentException: Some required information is missing from the connection string. The 'provider' keyword is always required.

Comment: naim, I have changed the connection string to the one you updated and it still throws the connection error sometimes

Comment: Yes. It fails sometimes. I was able to connect locally and even deploying it on server, but on rare times it throws this error.

Comment: This answer would be better and useful to other people if it explained what was being changed and why that would fix the problem.